# Passing objects as parameters by another object visual c++

Tags: object, visual-c++, parameters, sdl, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass an object by reference in c++. I get these errors:

Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Common' graphics.h  6   1   SDLGameDev

Error   2   error C2511: 'void Graphics::CreateWindow(Common &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Graphics'   4   1   SDLGameDev

I found answers about this area, but not any that covers how to do this:

```
object1.someFunction(object2);
```

Here is my code:

//Common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include "SDL.h"
#include "iostream"

class Common{
public:
    void Init();
    bool GetGameRunState(){ return GameRunState; }
    void SetGameRunState(bool x){ GameRunState = x; }
private:
    bool GameRunState;
};

#endif
```

//Commmon.cpp

```
#include "Common.h"

void Common::Init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        SetGameRunState(true);
    }
    else
    {
        SetGameRunState(false);
    }
}
```

//Graphics.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

class Graphics{
public:
    void CreateWindow(Common & co);
};

#endif
```

//Graphics.cpp

```
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Common.h"
void Graphics::CreateWindow(Common & co)
{
    if (co.GetGameRunState() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST for CreateWindow()\n";
    }
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "Common.h"
#include "Graphics.h"

Common co;
Graphics go;

int main(int argc, char * args[])
{
    co.Init();
    go.CreateWindow(co);
    while (co.GetGameRunState() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Game is running\n";
        SDL_Delay(2000);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included Common.h in the file Graphics.h so it doesn't know about the class.

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "Common.h"  // You need this line

class Graphics {
public:
    void CreateWindow(Common & co);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Wow, that was painful. Thanks alot Zammalad!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using singletons and put the initialisation of sdl, creation of the renderer and window etc all together in one class. Your question has already been answered.